# How to enable a dark theme by default, instead of toggle button?

Tags: html, css, themes

I'm specifically looking at this site here:

https://coin.dance/

In the upper left corner there is a dark/light theme toggle button, and I wanted to know how to enable something like this by default(dark style would be enabled before light).  I've been looking through the index.html, and all I can see of interest is this snippet of javascript:

```
<body class="dark">
<script type="text/javascript">
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
    // Registration was successful
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // registration failed :(
    console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
  });
}

function localStorageSave(key, value) {
  if (supportsLocalStorage()) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function localStorageLoad(key) {
  if (supportsLocalStorage()) {
    var value;
    try {
      value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }

    if (value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

function supportsLocalStorage() {
  try {
    if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
      try {
          localStorage.setItem('cd_ls_test', 'yes');
          if (localStorage.getItem('cd_ls_test') === 'yes') {
              localStorage.removeItem('cd_ls_test');
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      } catch(e) {
          return false;
      }
    }
  } catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

if (supportsLocalStorage()) {
  $('body').toggleClass('dark', localStorageLoad('dark'));
}
```

I'm interested because I like the overall theme of the site, and it's simplicity, but I wanted to know how it was done, and I cannot grasp where to start looking and editing.

Comment: What does enable by default mean? Where? On your own site or on this site specifically?

Comment: And if you're looking for the source... It's in script.js on the page. It's bound to the function toggleTheme()

Comment: I made a copy of the site so but I'm playing around with elements right now.  By default the page is a light theme, however when toggling the switch up top, it turns to dark.  I was trying to find out how to enable the dark theme by default, and the switch would toggle a the light theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with jquery just set a dark color background on your css by default and turn it on light color with button :

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked")){
  $(".bg").css("background-color","black");
  $(this).removeClass("clicked");
  }
  
  else
    
    {

      $(".bg").css("background-color","white")
      $(this).addClass("clicked")}
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0px;
}

.bg{
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:black;
}

.button{
  color:red;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:20px;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">
  <p class="button">Dark-light</p>
</div>
```